# How to find the user to which a given HTTP session belongs

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets, jira

### Intro:

I have a JIRA instance that is used by many external tools via REST. Some of these tools do not reuse the HTTP session they've created which results in the creation of a new session for each request.

### Problem:

The creation of too many session results in unacceptable resource consumption. So I'm looking for a way to:

- restrict the misbehaving clients to not create too many sessions by rejecting their login attempts - thus forcing their owners to fix their clients
- Invalidate the old sessions thus freeing resources on the server

But in order to do that **I need to know to which user given session belongs**, so when user X reaches the limit of lets say 5 session - I can either invalidate his older sessions or reject his request.

### Question:

How can I map the sessions to users from `HttpSessionListener` ?
Is there a better approach to achieving my goal ? Maybe something JIRA specific ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quite clever way to achieve my goal:

> So to work around this problem in a general sense we put together the
>   atlassian-bot-killer plugin.
>
> This works on sessions by inverting the idea.  A request may have
>   gotten a session but does it deserve to keep it?
>
> What this plugin does is watch every request via a servlet Filter and
>   checks if it has seen the session before.  If not it must be the first
>   request for that session.
>
> It then stores the original session timeout in the session itself and
>   sets the session inactivity timeout to be 1 minute.  If the session
>   makes a second request then it gets bumped back to the original
>   timeout of say 5 hours.  It gets upgraded if you will since we know
>   that the user agent is preserving sessions.
>
> A user behind a web browser often makes a second request milliseconds
>   after the first.  JavaScript, CSS files all count as requests.  So a
>   human user does not notice this at all.
>
> A web bot however does not preserve JSESSIONID cookies and hence is
>   always presenting as a first request.  These will then get a 1 minute
>   time out and hence die quickly.  The memory load on the server is
>   greatly reduced.
>
> REST requests from tools such as curl typically do no preserve
>   sessions either and hence they can fall into the same class of
>   request, even if they are done in terms of a user say via BASIC AUTH.
>
> The atlassian-bot-killer follows the same strategy on requests with a
>   known user however to be conservative it sets the inactivity time out
>   to be 10 minutes instead of 1.

Source: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/03/getting-rid-of-unwanted-http-sessions/

PS: Actually there is a ready to use plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.labs.atlassian-bot-killer/versions

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are normally "kept" by use of a session cookie. If the client doesn't pick up that cookie upon receipt, or doesn't include it with subsequent requests, you'll have the scenario you describe. There is no sure way to link the second request to the first, if the cookie is not included.

It sounds a bit strange that Jira would create a session for these requests. If they are really REST, they would be stateless and not require any session state. I don't know a thing about Jira installations though, but I would check that first.

Anyway, there are a few ways I can think of to narrow down the "bad" clients. One is to check for the "User-Agent" header in the incoming requests that cause a new session. You may discover a pattern of which user agents cause more new sessions, versus user agents that don't. It may or may not be an option but you could temporarily "disallow" those user agents and wait for them to complain to you ;-)
Other approach is via the requests IP address, which may allow you to trace back to the culprit and explain the issue.

Finally (and this is not a final solution but could aleviate the issue somewhat) you could shorten the time-to-live for sessions on that particular Jira instance. Again I don't know about Jira setup but typically this is supposed to be possible. If this instance also serves regular web users, take care as lowering the session timeout may impact them negatively (i.e. need to re-logon more often).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The REST api is BASIC auth protected and authenticated calls result in the creation of a new session unless the rest clients send the session cookies, which the bad clients do not do. They use some java based rest-api wrapper (jira rest client) that does not handle the sessions. `you could shorten the time-to-live` - That's not really an option because one of the clients creates around 2k sessions for a couple of minutes :) so I'll have to reduce the session timeout to a ridiculously low value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these tools are calling REST plugin points that you have created yourself: within the context of those methods, you can inject a [JiraAuthenticationContext](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/6.2.1/com/atlassian/jira/security/JiraAuthenticationContext.html) into your bean and call `getLoggedInUser()` to get the `ApplicationUser` object of the current user.

If non-null, you could then fetch the username and associate that with the session (`session.setAttribute(MY_USERNAME_KEY, applicationUser.getName())`).

If the external tools are simply accessing standard JIRA REST endpoints (ie. it's not your code), you would instead need to create a small new JIRA plugin with a [Servlet Filter](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/building-jira-add-ons/jira-plugins2-overview/jira-plugin-module-types/servlet-filter-plugin-module) plugin module using `location="before-dispatch"`, with a `<url-pattern>` covering the REST URLs that the bad clients are accessing. You should be able to inject `JiraAuthenticationContext` there too, and then just follow the same steps as above.

How you choose to enumerate the sessions and check against a maximum is up to you. One option, instead of directly inserting the name as a session attribute, is to instead insert a custom object as a session attribute that implements `HttpSessionBindingListener`, and then implement the appropriate callbacks within `valueBound` and `valueUnbound`. I have used the latter approach in JIRA for other session management purposes and I can confirm that the callbacks are called as expected.